# How to get the unchecked checkboxes in a js?

Tags: javascript

```js
var checkBoxesEnabled =document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-input');
var limit = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxesEnabled.length; i++) {
   checkBoxesEnabled[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
   var uncheckedcount = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxesEnabled.length; i++) {
          if(checkBoxesEnabled[i].checked === false > limit){
             alert('You cannot disable more than 2');
         }
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="excludedNumbers">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class=" form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="0" id="add0">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="add0">0</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="1" id="add1">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="add1">1</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="2" id="add2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="add2">2</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="3" id="add3">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="add3">3</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="4" id="add4">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="add4">4</label>
     </div>
      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="5" id="add5">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="add5">5</label>
     </div>
```

I have a `5 checkboxes`, Where all of them were **checked**.

The maximum 2 should be `unchecked`, with all the 3 **checked**.

*It didnt work, not sure what was wrong*

How could I get the **alert**, if more than 2 checkboxes were **unchecked**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the counter each time you find a checked checkbox and then compare it with the value of the limit variable. Raise an alert if the limit is crossed.

```
var checkBoxesEnabled =document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-input');
var limit = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxesEnabled.length; i++) {
   checkBoxesEnabled[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
   var uncheckedcount = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxesEnabled.length; i++) {
          if(checkBoxesEnabled[i].checked === false) uncheckedcount++;
          if (limit < uncheckedcount) {
                 alert('You cannot disable more than 2');
                 break;
          }
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1-** use `let` in your for loop

**2-** no need for a loop inside another loop

**3-** just use a counter to sum how many times a checkbox was unchecked and then compare to your limit

```js
const checkBoxesEnabled = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-input');
const limit = 2;
let uncheckedcount = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxesEnabled.length; i++) {
  checkBoxesEnabled[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (checkBoxesEnabled[i].checked === false) {
      uncheckedcount++;
    } else {
      uncheckedcount--;
    }
    if (uncheckedcount > limit) {
      alert('You cannot disable more than 2');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="excludedNumbers">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class=" form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="0" id="add0">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="add0">0</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="1" id="add1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="add1">1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="2" id="add2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="add2">2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="3" id="add3">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="add3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="4" id="add4">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="add4">4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" value="5" id="add5">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="add5">5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```